# Need a Bank WSDL to test using Soap UI

Tags: wsdl

I want a working BANK's WSDL with login credentials. So that i can test it using soap ui 4.5 for my project. please help me.

I tried goggling and I found the below wsdl and its not working 
http://www.testfire.net/bank/ws.asmx?WSDL

Can anyone Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can't get open WSDL specially Bank related.

So, you need to create your own dummy WSDL which replicates your requirement and test it accordingly.

Comment: I have added a wsdl that i found but its not working correctly